# Can't add data to Android sdcard on the emulator

Tags: android, sd-card

I can see the sd card in the file explorer with d--rwxr-x permission. When i tried adding any file to it it shows Failed to push the items. It is not adding even very small files.

Can you guys suggest how to fix this?

Comment: how are you pushing? command line or from Eclipse File Explorer?

Comment: Restart Eclipse, and don't forget to click on the device link to trigger the selection.

Comment: Restart doesn't work...its most likely a bug in Eclipse.  Try it with a small file < 1M it works in Eclipse but trying a 16M it fails at least for me.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you push files to the SD Card. First copy the file you want to push to the tools directory [android-sdk-windows]/tools/. Open a command prompt and if you don't have the tools directory in your path you will need to cd [drive]:\android-sdk-windows\tools. Then you just type this:

```
adb push [filename] /sdcard/[filename]
```

If you want to put the file into a subdirectory of sdcard you have to create it... you can do that in the adb shell or on the device with a file manager.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on Windows.
This site is very useful [deltafalcon.com](http://deltafalcon.com/2010/04/mounting-an-android-emulator-sd-card-image-in-windows/).